# Swift Eureka: Form Header Goes underneath NavigationBar

Tags: swift, eureka-forms

I called a performSegue from a tableView and pushed to a FormVC. However, my header went underneath the navigationBar despite that the UIView is offset 100 pts in the y axis. 
[image]

My code as follows:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "EventsDetails" {
            let destVC = segue.destination as! EventsDetailsViewController
        }
    }

class EventsDetailsViewController: FormViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        form +++
            Section(){ section in
                section.header = {
                    var header = HeaderFooterView<UIView>(.callback({
                        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: 100, height: 180))
                        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 10, width: 80, height: 80))
                        imageView.backgroundColor = .red
                        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width / 2
                        imageView.clipsToBounds = true

                        let nameLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 120, y: 40, width: 150, height: 20))
                        nameLabel.text = "Test Text"
                        nameLabel.backgroundColor = .blue
                        nameLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18.0)

                        view.addSubview(imageView)
                        view.addSubview(nameLabel)
                        view.backgroundColor = .white
                        return view
                    }))
                    header.height = { 200 }
                    return header
                }()
        }

    }

}
```

Is there a way to move the view down to the bottom of the navBar? By the way I use storyboard. I know this may be a primitive question, but some advice is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: set .. self.navigationbar.opaque = false .

Comment: @sourav doesn't work. I do not want it to be opaque, but i want the view to move down to the bottom of the navBar

Comment: @Koh I can't reproduce your problem, for me works just fine, I simply add a viewController into NavigationController and one TabBarController I don't change any constraint